# Шаблон конструктора копирования - как правильно реализовать?

Tags: c++

Начал изучать с++
Для примера делал класс `A<DataType>` обобщенного массива.
Понадобился конструктор `A<DataType>(A<SrcType>& src)` который приводит данные типа SrcType из src и инициализирует ими массив.
Однако такой конструктор не имеет доступа к защищенным (private) членам `A<SrcType>`

Пример программы:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class DataType>
class A
{
//public:
    DataType data[100];
    unsigned len;
public:
    A(DataType*d, unsigned l=0):len(l) {for(unsigned i=0;i<len;data[i]=d[i],i++);}

    template<class SrcType> A(const A<SrcType>& src);

    ~A(){}

    template<class Type>
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, A<Type>);
};

template <class DataType>
template <class SrcType>
A<DataType>::A(const A<SrcType>& src) : len(src.len)
{
    for(unsigned i=0; i<len; data[i]=src.data[i],i++);
}

template <class DataType>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& s, A<DataType> a)
{
    for(unsigned i=0;i<a.len;i++)
    s<<i<<" - "<<a.data[i]<<endl;
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    int d[7]={1,2,3,10,20,30,0};
    A<int> a(d,7);
    A<bool> c(a);
    cout<<a;
    cout<<c;
    return 0;
}
```

Вот что говорит компилятор:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in testclass (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++ -Wall -fexceptions -g  -c /home/tensor/cd/testclass/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
/home/tensor/cd/testclass/main.cpp: In instantiation of «A<DataType>::A(const A<SrcType>&) [with SrcType = int; DataType = bool]»:
/home/tensor/cd/testclass/main.cpp:43:16:   required from here
/home/tensor/cd/testclass/main.cpp:9:14: ошибка: «unsigned int A<int>::len» is private
     unsigned len;
              ^
/home/tensor/cd/testclass/main.cpp:24:52: ошибка: в данном контексте
 A<DataType>::A(const A<SrcType>& src) : len(src.len)
                                                    ^
/home/tensor/cd/testclass/main.cpp:8:22: ошибка: «int A<int>::data [100]» is private
     DataType data[100];
                      ^
/home/tensor/cd/testclass/main.cpp:26:46: ошибка: в данном контексте
     for(unsigned i=0; i<len; data[i]=src.data[i],i++);
                                              ^
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
4 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Если раскомментировать public: все работает, но хотелось бы обойтись без этого.
Что можно сделать?

Comment: Вместо ключевого слова class , рекомендую использовать typename

Comment: Почему? Вроде бы `template<class T>` и `template<typename T>` - синонимы?

Comment: Потому что в мире C++ программеров принято применять именно typename. О деталях лучше почитайте в книге Скотта Майерса.

Comment: Заказал. Доставят на неделе :-)

Comment: Зачем заказывать, когда можно найти в инете? Не рационально, а если уж понравится, то пойти и купить в бумаге, чтобы подчеркнуть те правила, которые реально помогают именно тебе!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете объявить все инстанциации `A` friend'ами.

Для этого добавьте внутрь класса `A` следующее:

```
template<typename> friend class A;
```

Заметьте, что

```
template<typename T> friend class A<T>;
```

не скомпилируется.

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно

Comment: Пожалуйста!

Comment: Не совсем понятно.
`template<typename T> friend class A<T>;` не компилируется, так как класс `A<T>` на этот момент не определен?

Comment: @oberlicht: если я правильно понимаю, это считается частичной специализацией, и таким образом противоречит пункту 14.5.3/9 стандарта, который запрещает такое для шаблонов _классов_.